# Finding a 2D array inside a bigger 2D array

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I am able to solve the problem for those test cases where there is only 1 string per row.But i fail if there are multiple strings in a single row.

For example:

Test Case Type 1:

Big matrix:

```
7283455864
6731158619
8988242643
3830589324
2229505813
5633845374
6473530293
7053106601
0834282956
4607924137
```

Small Matrix:

```
9505
3845
3530
```

I pass these kinds of test cases as 9505 occurs at most 1 time inside Big Matrix.

Test Case Type:2

Big Matrix:

```
7652157548860692421022503
9283597467877865303553675
4160389485250089289309493
2583470721457150497569300
3220130778636571709490905
3588873017660047694725749
9288991387848870159567061
4840101673383478700737237
8430916536880190158229898
8986106490042260460547150
2591460395957631878779378
1816190871689680423501920
0704047294563387014281341
8544774664056811258209321
9609294756392563447060526
0170173859593369054590795
6088985673796975810221577
7738800757919472437622349
5474120045253009653348388
3930491401877849249410013
1486477041403746396925337
2955579022827592919878713
2625547961868100985291514
3673299809851325174555652
4533398973801647859680907
```

Small Matrix:

```
5250
1457
8636
7660
7848
```

I fail these kinds of test cases where 5250(or any other row in small matrix) occurs more than once inside same row of bigger matrix:

Below is the code i have written:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;


public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      HashMap<Integer,Integer> rowCol=new HashMap();      
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            //bigger array
            int R = in.nextInt();
            int C = in.nextInt();
            String G[] = new String[R];
            for(int G_i=0; G_i < R; G_i++){
                G[G_i] = in.next();
            }
            //smaller array
            int r = in.nextInt();
            int c = in.nextInt();
            String P[] = new String[r];
            for(int P_i=0; P_i < r; P_i++){
                P[P_i] = in.next();
            }

          for(int i = 0;i<R-r;i++)//obvious
            {
              for(int j = 0; j<r;j++ )//obvious
                {
                  //if string found put in map(row at which found,column at whch found)
                  if(G[i].indexOf(P[j])>=0)//string found
                    {
                      rowCol.put(i,G[i].indexOf(P[j]));
                    }
                }
            }

          //now check if rows are consecutive(1,2,3) and columns are equal(1,1,1)
          HashSet<Integer> mc = new HashSet<Integer>(rowCol.values());//if size==1 then same column
          ArrayList<Integer> mr = new ArrayList<Integer>(rowCol.keySet());
          int count = 0;
          for(int m = 0 ;m<mr.size()-1;m++)//checking if keys are consecutive
            {

              if(mr.get(m)+1==mr.get(m+1))
                {
                  count++;//how many values are same ,hw mny strings found at same index
                }
            }

          //System.out.println(count+"+++++"+(mr.size()-1));
          //System.out.println( rowCol.values().size()+"==="+r);

          if(mc.size()==1 && count==(mr.size()-1) && rowCol.keySet().size()==r)//all column same && all rows are consecutive && 
            {
              System.out.println("YES");
            }
          else
            {
              System.out.println("NO");
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: i am failing to see any `2D array` here.

Comment: I did not use 2D int arrays as it was getting difficult.I used Strings instead as earlier i was trying to use regex.Sorry for the faulty header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is faulty.

```
  for(int i = 0;i<R-r;i++)//obvious
    {
      for(int j = 0; j<r;j++ )//obvious
        {
          //if string found put in map(row at which found,column at whch found)
          if(G[i].indexOf(P[j])>=0)//string found
            {
              rowCol.put(i,G[i].indexOf(P[j]));
            }
        }
    }
```

This goes through all the lines in G, and all the lines of P. If that line of P exists in that line of G, it will be placed in the map.

But first, it only tells you that *some* line from P is in that line of G, it doesn't tell you which line. This will mean it also fails when you are looking for a small matrix which is just like an existing matrix but different order of lines.

Second, if there is more than one line of the small matrix in the line of G, it will keep the index of the lower line from P. That is, if you have both 5250 and 7660 in the same line in G, it will keep just the index of the 7660 and ignore the 5250.

```
ArrayList<Integer> mr = new ArrayList<Integer>(rowCol.keySet());
```

You are using `mr` to check for consecutive line, but you are filling it with the key set from a `HashMap`. This means that the order is not guaranteed - you could get the line numbers in the order 5,3,1,2,4 or whatever.

You should write your program with different logic. Don't try to collect all the locations of all the lines. Find the location of the first line of P, and immediately check if the rest are in place. Say you found the first line of P in line 30 at index 15. Then check if line 2 is in line 31 at index 15, and if line 3 is in line 32 at index 15, and so on.

If all matched, print "YES", and **return from the method**. Do not continue the loop. But if not all matched, keep looking for P[0].

- Note that there may be more than one occurrence of P[0] in the same line in G. So if matching failed, continue to search in the same line of G until no more occurrences of P[0] occur, and only then move to the next line of G.
- If you didn't find any matches, then at the end of the loop you can print "NO".